# Where can I download network drivers for Ubuntu 20.04.1 after installing?

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I just recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 to my Toshiba Satellite CL45 Laptop using the Rufus USB Installer and I have no ability to connect to the internet. I remember specifically selecting the option in the process that said, "Install 3rd party software for some drivers" or something similar to that. Now after booting up, I can't connect to the internet and have no idea on how to find the correct drivers needed to make this work. Any help is great!

Comment: The question lacks key data: WifI or Cabled? What chipset is the network hardware? Did internet work on the Try Ubuntu environment of the installer? How do you know it's a driver and not something simpler (like a hardware/keyboard switch)? Avoid asking about specific solutions (like "drivers") if what you really want is help troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: Blake, edit your question and include as much additional information as you can, as user535733 suggested. (Is the issue with Ethernet or Wi-Fi? Do you know what chip set you have? Were you able to connect to the Internet while running the Live ISO?)

Comment: Start by editing your question with the output of `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.